# Python Selenium send keys without Input element

Tags: python, html, sql, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the process of pulling data from a website using SQL. However, the example website that I am working on doesn't have an input field to paste the SQL query via Python. It means that I can manually click on the text box and type it in, but I cannot program Python to automatically paste the query in. I have been inspecting the website's html and css but found nothing about input field, just DIVs and spans.

Website: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

I want to program so that I can replace the existing query, paste my query via Jupyter Notebook and it will automatically populate the "SQL Statement" text box.

I am using Selenium library and messing around with different Xpaths, but nothing has worked so far.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all')
time.sleep(3)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tryitform']/div/div[6]/div[1]").click()
time.sleep(1)
```

Expected result:

The "SQL Statement" text box on this website will be populated with the query I have from my Python code.

For example:

```
sqlQuery = browser.find_element_by_id(‘input_field_sql_for_example’)
sqlQuery.send_keys(‘SELECT * FROM Customers where City in("Berlin");’)
```